# Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference in angular-4 and using angular-cli

Tags: angular

I am using ng2-admin dashboard library, I have updated to latest version before a week, seems from last few days I am unable to run my application in IE11 but its opened and run in Chrome and Mozilla browser.

below is my files relates to this issue,polyfills.ts and package.json and error,

1. error:

> DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For        more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
>        my-comp-list
>        HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
>        my-comp-list
>   SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference
>   vendor.bundle.js (23012,5)

2. package.json:
   `{
    "name": "ng2-admin",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Angular and Bootstrap 4 Admin Template.",
    "author": "Akveo ",
    "homepage": "http://akveo.github.io/ng2-admin/",
    "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin.git"
    },
    "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin/issues"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "changelog": "standard-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve --deploy-url \"http://localhost:4200/\"",
    "start:hmr": "ng serve --hmr",
    "start:aot": "ng serve --aot",
    "start:prod": "ng serve --prod",
    "start:prod:aot": "ng serve --prod --aot",
    "build": "npm run clean:dist && ng build && gulp default",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod",
    "build:prod:aot": "npm run build:prod -- --aot",
    "build:ci": "npm run build:prod && npm run build:prod:aot",
    "build:demo": "npm run build:prod:aot -- --base-href \"http://akveo.com  /ng2-admin/\"",
    "test": "ng test -sr",
    "test:coverage": "npm run clean:coverage && ng test -sr -cc",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/app/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:coverage": "npm run rimraf -- coverage",
    "docs:deploy": "wintersmith build -C docs && gh-pages -d docs/build",
    "docs:serve": "wintersmith preview -C docs"
    },
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "4.1.0",
   "@angular/common": "4.1.0",
   "@angular/compiler": "4.1.0",
   "@angular/core": "4.1.0",
   "@angular/forms": "4.1.0",
   "@angular/http": "4.1.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.0",
   "@angular/platform-server": "4.1.0",
   "@angular/router": "4.1.0",
   "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.25",
   "@ngx-translate/core": "6.0.1",
   "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
   "amcharts3": "github:amcharts/amcharts3",
   "ammap3": "github:amcharts/ammap3",
   "angular2-datatable": "0.6.0",
   "animate.css": "3.5.2",
   "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
   "chart.js": "1.1.1",
   "chartist": "0.10.1",
   "chroma-js": "1.3.3",
   "ckeditor": "4.6.2",
   "core-js": "2.4.1",
   "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
   "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
   "fullcalendar": "3.3.1",
   "google-maps": "3.2.1",
   "ionicons": "2.0.1",
   "jquery": "3.2.1",
   "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
   "leaflet": "0.7.7",
   "leaflet-map": "0.2.1",
   "lodash": "4.17.4",
   "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.6",
   "ng2-completer": "1.3.1",
   "ng2-handsontable": "0.48.0",
   "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "4.0.0",
   "ng2-smart-table": "1.0.3",
   "ng2-tree": "2.0.0-alpha.5",
   "ngx-uploader": "2.2.5",
   "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
   "roboto-fontface": "0.7.0",
   "rxjs": "5.1.1",
   "zone.js": "0.8.5",

   "@ng-idle/core": "*",
   "@ng-idle/keepalive": "*",
   "moment": "*",
   "ng2-toastr": "*",
   "owasp-password-strength-test": "*"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "@angular/cli": "1.0.1",
       "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.0",
       "@types/fullcalendar": "2.7.40",
       "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
       "@types/jquery": "2.0.41",
       "@types/jquery.slimscroll": "1.3.30",
       "@types/lodash": "4.14.61",
       "@types/node": "6.0.69",
       "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
       "gh-pages": "0.12.0",
       "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
       "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
       "karma": "1.4.1",
       "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
       "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
       "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
       "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
       "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
       "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
       "protractor": "5.1.0",
       "rimraf": "2.6.1",
       "standard-changelog": "1.0.1",
       "stylelint": "7.10.1",
       "ts-node": "2.0.0",
       "tslint": "4.5.0",
       "tslint-eslint-rules": "3.5.1",
       "tslint-language-service": "0.9.2",
       "typescript": "2.3.2",
       "typogr": "0.6.6",
       "underscore": "1.8.3",
       "wintersmith": "2.2.5",
       "wintersmith-sassy": "1.1.0",

   ```
   "del": "*",
   "gulp": "*"
   ```

   }
   }
   `
3. polyfills.ts
   `
   /**

   - This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the  app.
   - You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
     *
   - This file is divided into 2 sections:
   - 1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are  sorted by browsers.
   - 2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be  loaded before your main
   - file.
     *
   - The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last  versions of browsers that
   - automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >=  55 (including Opera),
   - Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
     *
   - Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser- support.html
     */

     /****************************************************************************    ***********************
   - BROWSER POLYFILLS
     */

   /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
   // import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
   // import 'core-js/es6/object';
   // import 'core-js/es6/function';
   // import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
   // import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
   // import 'core-js/es6/number';
   // import 'core-js/es6/math';
   // import 'core-js/es6/string';
   // import 'core-js/es6/date';
   // import 'core-js/es6/array';
   // import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
   // import 'core-js/es6/map';
   // import 'core-js/es6/set';

   /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG  elements */
   // import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

   /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following to support `@angular/animation`.  */
   // import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save  web-animations-js`.

   /** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
   import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
   import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

   /** ALL Firefox browsers require the following to support    `@angular/animation`. **/
    // import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save    web-animations-js`.

   /**************************************************************************** ***********************

   - Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
     */
     import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.

     /**************************************************************************** ***********************

     - APPLICATION IMPORTS
       */

     /**

     - Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
     - Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
       */
       // import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.

`

Comment: found some links bit similar to issue on github [747](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/747), [6075](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6075), also 6036 and i tried with different zone version such as 0.8.4,0.8.5, 0.8.7, 0.8.8, but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got similar issue like yours.

I have resolved my issue by adding polyfills:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

For more details, you can refer to my blog post: http://kosmisch.net/Blog/DotNetEssential/Archive/2017/5/20/issue-unable-to-get-property-apply-of-undefined-or-null-reference-occurred-in-angular-4-vs2017-153-aspnet-core-20.html

Comment: thank you....this solved my issue and i am able to open app in IE11, but now i am getting another Error on console which relates to something like "SCRIPT5022: SecurityError polyfills.bundle.js (6375,25)"....so have you face this issue also? ...